# How to do client-specific imports in a React frontend?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm working on a new project where I'm taking a full-stack application and decoupling the UI from the backend -- so basically our backend will be just a JSON API a new React-based frontend talks to.

The way our current full-stack architecture works is we have a base application in `/core/app` and then a client overrides folder for each client `/clients/client{1,2,3}/app` and then our file include logic checks the client folder first and then the core folder as a fallback.

Like php `include_path` precedence logic.

I feel pretty confident in how I'll setup the core app, but I'm not quite sure how I'll handle this override concept.

Ideally when I call:
`import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent`

I know import statements can't be dynamic, but I'm looking for a solution to check in `/clients/client1/components/MyComponent` first and then `/core/component/components/MyComponent` second.

What is the recommended way to handle this sort of usecase?  I thought about trying to be fancy with symlinks (ie: by default, each client gets a symlink to every single item in the core and then they'd override it as needed and replace the symlink).

That seems kind of hacky and I'm not sure how it'd work with hot-reloading so I'm hoping there's a more elegant approach.

Comment: If what you want it to import from `/clients/client1/components/MyComponent` and *if that file doesn't exist* import from `/core/component/components/MyComponent` I think you might be able to do that by setting path aliases in your Webpack config.

Look into Webpack's `resolve.modules`

Comment: @aaronjkrause I believe you mean `resolve.alias`, not `resolve.modules`.

Comment: Thanks for reference.  `resolve.alias` is close -- it would let me globally decide whether to use a `client/client` or `core` folder with `import`, but it doesn't look to have the fallback logic I'd need.  This did set me on the right path though, I think `NormalModuleReplacementLoader` will do the trick though: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/  I'll have to test to verify, but I believe it'd let me do something like `import '$APP/components/MyComponent' and then I could turn around in WebPack and do a test against my client vs core folders.